# Entity Field Query

Tags: entities, database

I don't think I am yet grasping how entity field query works, all I want to do is get the ids of all the nodes connected to my node via an entity reference, how do I write that?

Answer (score 3):

You want to find the entity IDs that are referenced from a node you've already loaded?

If the reference field is called 'field_reference', then:

```
global $language_content;
$langcode = $language_content->language;
$references = $node->field_reference[$langcode];
$target_ids = array();
foreach ($references as $delta => $reference) {
  $target_ids[] = $reference['target_id'];
}
```

Your mileage may vary with the language stuff.

Note that you usually want to keep track of the entity type (e.g. 'node' or 'user'). You can't really do anything with an entity without knowing its type.

So you might want something like:

```
$target_ids[$reference['target_type']][] = $reference['target_id'];
```